# Using Viete's Product show that $\frac{3}{\pi}= \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2} * \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}{2} * ...$

Tags: products, euler-product

Viete's product is
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} * \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2} * \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2}*... 
$$

Show that

$$
\frac{3}{\pi} = \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2} * \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}{2} * \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}}{2}*...
$$

This uses Euler's product with $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and my thoughts were to find which $\theta=\frac{3}{\pi}$ but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the right hand side could be rewritten $\cos(\pi/12) \cos(\pi/24) \cos(\pi/48) \cdots$ and the partial products would be equal to $\frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{\sin(\pi/6)}{\sin(\pi/(3\cdot 2^n))}$.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti $ \frac{sin{\theta}}{\theta}=cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}*cos{\frac{\theta}{4}}*cos{\frac{\theta}{8}}... $